# improve android tabs actionbar

Tags: java, android

I'm using [this](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) link for create custom tab in android. Now my problem is how to remove the dark horizontal line in center?

[image]

I want to have some thing like this:

[image]

Comment: You want to remove that line so you have 2 instead of 3?

Comment: Sorry, so you want to remove the lines that are covering the text?

Comment: No, I want to remove the line that shown by black arrow. I mean the horizontal dark line in the center.

Comment: You could make your actionbar transparent, and set the background underneath it to the same color as your tab backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

In your styles.xml in your main app theme set the windowContentOverlay to null. Something like the code below.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: I can't use setElevation(0) for getSupportActionBar